# Google Sheets: Inserting checkbox to an entire column (even if it grows)

Tags: google-sheets

I know you can fill a column with checkboxes easily.

But what if new rows are added? How to fill them too with checkboxes **automatically**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **data validation** rules.

[image]

When selecting the range, use something like K2:K and the checkbox will be inserted in new rows too.

[image]